# How can I include a simple array in List.of()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am having a lot of trouble with putting an array as a parameter in one of my REST API methods. My server will be retrieving data from a separate API which requires all the below fields to be set.

```
public class Article {
    private String by;
    private int descendants;
    private int[] kids;
    private int id;
    private int score;
    private int time;
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private String url;
```

In another class, I have the following method:

```
    @Override
    public List<Article> selectAllArticles() {
        //TODO: argument fix needed
        return List.of(new Article("by", "descendants", [???], "id", "score", "title", "type", "url"));
    }
```

The [???] is where I'm trying to figure out how to write out the array.

Comment: You mean something like ```new int[] {1,2,3}```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either return an array:

```
public Object[] selectAllArticles() {
        return new Object[] {"by", "descendants", [???], "id", "score", "title", "type", "url"};
}
```

or if you really need specific type you don't need a List<?> of length 1, simply return the Article:

```
public Article selectAllArticles() {
        return new Article("by", "descendants", [???], "id", "score", "title", "type", "url");
}
```

I also want to note that [???] is not a thing in Java

Comment: Oh, the [???] is where I was confused and did not know how to write the array in that parameter spot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an int[] array for the *kids* property, you can use ArrayList so that initialization with size won't be an issue.

*Or*

If the *kid* property is just for only mentioning the number of kids then an array is not needed; just *int* would do.

Also, if only one article is going to be sent, then you can send the article itself instead of packing it in a list.